# How can I make the gravity of a rigid body work after deactivating the animation, after applying a bake to it?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I'm making a ball enter a soccer goal and collide with its net and then it falls by inertia and it´s gravity. I have already done the part where the ball enters the goal and hits the net, by 'bake' the ball animation, and then I applied rigid body physics on it to animate it specifically after it hits the net so that gravity makes it fall to the ground, but it does not go down and it is levitating continuously in the animation, I have already tried the procedure of disabling its animation in its physics section in 'settings' in the 'frame' following the moment it hits the soccer goal net. Everything is done manually. I will be very grateful for your help.

Below I put my work to you can evaluate it. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to go to the Scene :: Rigid Body World, and select Bake or Bake All:

[image]

[image]

I think you might need to adjust the start time = 141-ish and also turn UP the friction and bounciness on the net RB:

[image]

to higher values so the ball doesn't go through the net:

[image]

Comment: Indeed that is the solution I was looking for, thank you, however, I am in doubt and I wanted to take the opportunity to ask if it is possible and apologize for that at the same time. Why the ball instead of falling immediately down, has a kind of rebound physics?
---
Sorry, i didn't see the update respond, thank you you help me a lot!

Comment: @LightPure - I also thought this look too much of a "dead ball" instead of bouncing back towards the kicker, as the net would push it.  This is where you have to "play around" with both the net and ball bounciness to get more realistic.   You might also need to play with the Cloth parameters, perhaps to add more tension or internal springs.  Or perhaps a momentary Wind Force giving more "pushback" at the moment of hitting the net.  Now you may also have to *fake it* a bit: put a hidden object that is also passive R.B. where the ball strikes.   In summary this becomes the hair-pulling exercise!

Comment: @LightPure -- another suggestion: post this followup question specifically, on this site or even on blender on Discord or [blenderartists](https://blenderartists.org/).